# Why StringBuilder equals() method is not overridden?

Tags: java, equals, stringbuilder

Can anyone explain to me why creators of java chose not to override Object equals() method in StringBuilder class?
Thanks!

Comment: could you eleborate why you think they should have done so?

Comment: Why do you want to know if two `StringBuilder` instances are equal (as opposed to the `String`s built by them)?